# how to create query,send events and listen for query results from java in WSO CEP?

Tags: java, wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I read the documentation provided on the website but it wasnt much informative about how to connect to the server and access its CEP features from java.For example does it accept POJO as event model or is it just xml?
Can we create event models and queries from java?If so how,and how to fetch results from java?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your usecase Armin? Do you want to send some events to CEP using a java client and then receive the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not much clear about your requirement, but thought of informing you about the following two options:

1. Send events using a java client and let wso2-cep server do the processing. 
   In this case, queries are not defined in your java code, but they're defined by you in the cep server (which are SQL-like queries). You only write a java-client to send events to the CEP server.
   Refer to sample java code [1], which is the java client used in CEP sample [2] (See step 2 in 'Execusing the sample' section).
2. Use 'Siddhi' as a library.
   WSO2 CEP contains an event processing engine, called 'Siddhi' which is written in Java. You can use Siddhi as a java library. 
   Refer to sample java code hosted at [3]. Also, you may refer to the blog post [4] (be mindful that the blog post refers to an older version of Siddhi).

Update:
Based on your comment, I think what you need to do is to use the 'Admin Services' exposed by WSO2-CEP server. Refer to [5] which has an introduction on 'Admin Services'.
You can refer to one of the integration testcases [6] to understand the usage of admin services.

Hope this helps...

[1]https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/cep/3.1.0/modules/samples/producers/service-stats

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Sample+0001+-+Simple+Pass-through+with+WSO2Event

[3] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/dilini/siddhi_sample/siddhi-examples.zip

[4] http://suhothayan.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-siddhi-cep-as-java-library.html

[5] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Calling+Admin+Services+from+Apps

[6] https://github.com/wso2/product-cep/blob/master/modules/integration/tests-integration/tests/src/test/java/org/wso2/carbon/integration/test/processflow/EventFlowTestCase.java

Comment: as you mentioned, I need the first scenario where I use a java client to send both events and the queries. I have a web interface where the client can define their own streams and add their own queries on their streams based on siddhi query language. In this case I need my java client be able to setup and destroy queries dynamically on wso2-cep server. Is this possible?if so how?

Comment: Clear, Armin. Then you can use Admin Services. I will update my answer.